# Transformar String em Array - Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Possuo uma `String` da seguinte forma:

```
[["155","123RET"],["156","124RET"]]
```

Ou seja dentro dela a dois `subArrays` que eu preciso adicionar um item ainda em cada um, minha necessidade é que no fim esses arrays fiquem da seguinte forma:

```
[["1","155","123RET"],["2","156","124RET"]]
```

Preciso converter essa `string` original em um `array` para poder alterar eles de acordo com a minha necessidade.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
def array = Eval.me(suprimentoRetEstoque)
```

E meu retorno foi assim:

```
[[155, 123RET],[156, 124RET]]
```

Porém não estou conseguindo percorrer esses subArrays, há alguma forma de converter uma **string** em **array** diferente dessa `Eval.me()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)!**

[O uso do `Eval` não é a melhor solução na maioria dos casos](http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2011/01/18/jslint-messages-eval-is-evil/), alem de que essa solução falhará quando o tipo de dados for alterado, ele não é adaptável.

Então, é melhor usar [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def arrayString = "[10, 1, 9]"
def arrayList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ids)

println "${arrayList[0]}"; // Mostra o primeiro item do array (que no caso é outro array)
```

Para **percorrer** o `Array` e os subArrays use `.each`:

```
arrayList.each { array ->
    array.each { valor ->
        // Aqui voce manipula o valor de cada subArray
        println "${valor}";
    };
};
```

Que em **java** *"puro"* seria:

```
for (Array array : list) {
    for (String valor : array) {
        // Aqui voce manipula o valor de cada subArray
        System.out.println(valor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Como eu consigo precorrer esse array gerado?

Comment: Pelo que diz na documentação (http://grails.asia/groovy-list-tutorial-and-examples), esse objeto é um `ArrayList` do Java, creio que um `forEach` resolve.

Comment: É que minha necessidade é justamente essa, se tu puder postar uma resposta com isso eu te agradeço ;)

Comment: Editei, vê se responde sua duvida (estou sem compilador, qualquer erro que der pode me reportar)

Comment: Esquece Lucas descobri como fazer, vou postar uma resposta mostrando como ficou meu código no final, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Com o auxilio do @LucasHenrique consegui resolver minha questão de converter uma string em um array e conseguir adicionar algo nos subArrays, meu código final ficou assim:

```
def numEstoqueManual = numeroEstoqueRetornoManual as Integer
def arrayRetorno = new JsonSlurper().parseText(suprimentoRetEstoque)
def lista = []
def listaFinal = []

arrayRetorno.each { array ->

    lista.add(numEstoqueManual)
    array.each { valor ->
        lista.add(valor)
    };
    numEstoqueManual++
    listaFinal.add(lista)
    lista = []
};
```

Novamente obrigado pela ajuda Lucas